# Converting date values in database query

Tags: java, sql, selenium, automation

I am writing Selenium tests to verify values on my UI against a source system. I am running sql queries against source db to obtain my expected results then I am navigating to a page on the UI to assert the db value against the value shown on UI.

Problem I have now is that I am verifying some dates. The db holds the date in a value such as '2017-09-18 00:00:00.000' where as the UI has transformed this into a nicer readable format '18 September 2017'.

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this. I started thinking to try and change the query so it transforms the date into the same format as my UI but struggling to find a way of doing this. Wondering if there is an easier way around this problem.

Comment: which database are you trying to get date from..? MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform/format values from db into nicer format with following code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(rs.getDate(1));
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(timeStamp.getTime()); 
System.out.println(date);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(date);
```

Try this out, hope this help. Tweak if neccessary, but generally this should be it.

Comment: Little bit of tweaking needed but main think I learned there was about SimpleDateFormat which was just what I needed. Worked a treat so thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I can help!